# Standard deviation of binned values with `scipy.stats.binned_statistic`

Tags: python, statistics, binning

When I bin my data accordingly to `scipy.stats.binned_statistic` ([see here for example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html)), how do I get the error (that is the standard deviation) on the average binned values?

For example, if I bin my data as following:

```
windspeed = 8 * np.random.rand(500)
boatspeed = .3 * windspeed**.5 + .2 * np.random.rand(500)
bin_means, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(windspeed,
             boatspeed, statistic='median', bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(windspeed, boatspeed, 'b.', label='raw data')
plt.hlines(bin_means, bin_edges[:-1], bin_edges[1:], colors='g', lw=5,
        label='binned statistic of data')
plt.legend()
```

how do I get the standard deviation on the `bin_means`?

Comment: What is the definition of the error on the bin_means? You should probably say what it is in the problem statement.

Comment: @RobertDodier, standard deviation would do fine.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about this is to construct a probability density estimate from the histogram (this is just a question of normalizing the histogram appropriately), and then computing the standard deviation or any other statistic for the estimated density.

The appropriate normalization is whatever is needed to get the area under the histogram to be 1. As for computing statistics for the density estimate, work from the definition of the statistic as `integral(p(x)*f(x), x, -infinity, +infinity)`, substituting the density estimate for `p(x)` and whatever is needed for `f(x)`, e.g. `x` and `x^2` to get the first and second moments, from which you calculate the variance and then the standard deviation.

I'll post some formulas tomorrow, or maybe someone else wants to give it a try in the meantime. You might be able to look up some formulas, but my advice is to always try to work out the answer before resorting to looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late to answer, but I was wondering how to do the same thing and came across this question. I think calculating it with `stats.binned_statistic_2d` should be possible, but I haven't figured it out yet. For now I calculated it manually, like so (note than in my code I use a fixed number of equally spaced bins):

```
windspeed = 8 * numpy.random.rand(500)
boatspeed = .3 * windspeed**.5 + .2 * numpy.random.rand(500)
bin_means, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(windspeed,
         boatspeed, statistic='median', bins=10)

stds = []

# Match each value to the bin number it belongs to
pairs = zip(boatspeed, binnumber)

# Calculate stdev for all elements inside each bin
for n in list(set(binnumber)):  # Iterate over each bin
    in_bin = [x for x, nbin in pairs if nbin == n]  # Get all elements inside bin n
    stds.append(numpy.std(in_bin))

# Calculate the locations of the bins' centers, for plotting
bin_centers = []

for i in range(len(bin_edges) -  1):
    center = bin_edges[i] + (float(bin_edges[i + 1]) - float(bin_edges[i]))/2.
    bin_centers.append(center)

# Plot means
pyplot.figure()
pyplot.hlines(bin_means, bin_edges[:-1], bin_edges[1:], colors='g', lw=5,
    label='binned statistic of data')

# Plot stdev as vertical lines, probably can also be done with errorbar
pyplot.vlines(bin_centers, bin_means - stds, bin_means + stds)

pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Resulting plot (minus the data points):
[image]

You have to be careful with the bins. In the code I'm working on using this, one of the bins has no points and I have to adjust my calculations of the stdev accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

just change this line

```
bin_std, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(windspeed,
             boatspeed, statistic='std', bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```